# Selenium как изменить этот CSS-элемент?

Tags: python, css, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Как я могу получить и изменить стиль CSS, выделенный  на фотографии?[image]

Пробовал что то по типу [этого](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66192562/how-to-change-css-in-selenium-full-source-code).Но получил такую ошибку.

[image]
Предполагаю что ошибка тут.

[image]

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Мне нужно изменить обеденную переменную margin-top: 30px;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Потому что надо не `margin-top`, а `marginTop`.

Comment: Извиняюсь, он его немного не там меняет но мне это помогло)

Comment: При выполнении этого кода:                               
element=driver.find_element(By.XPATH,'/html/body/div[10]/div/div/div[4]/div/div[2]/figure[1]/figcaption)
print(element.value_of_css_property("marginTop"))
 driver.execute_script("arguments[0].style.marginTop = '-30px';", element)
 print(element.value_of_css_property("marginTop"))                                                                                          
Я получаю дубликат [margin-top](https://goo.su/S9i2), можно ли как то изменить существующий?

Comment: @SL_, а зачем???

Comment: ,Ну если изменять, а не создавать новый то он автоматом меняется у всех. А при создании его приходится прогонять через for. Так что только в целях быстродействия.

Comment: @SL_, тогда добавь такой же стиль с нужным селектором в конец body.

Comment: ,А можно пример, а то не очень понятно.

Comment: @SL_, `document.body.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', '<style>[dir] .article:not(.article-mobile) > figure { margin-top: -30px; } </style>')`

Comment: он все равно его переписывает) Только не в style а отдельным экземпляром, но несмотря на это его достаточно проставить в одном экземпляре и в остальных он проставиться сам так что я добился того чего хотел большое спасибо. Завтра для вас еще вопросов сделаю)